# Video View Layout issues

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a Dialog box that will display a video (quick tutorial) before the first levels

I got the video and the view working fine but I have a problem in the layout of my dialog.

here is what I want:

A video view centered horizontally and taking as much space as it can.

Under that a button Play.

Unfortunately I can't get that for some reason.

I think it comes from the video view not being launched at the moment of the creation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </VideoView>

        </LinearLayout>
 <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_below="@+id/video"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the closest I got to but its still no good

Hope you can help

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/test"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button android:id="@+id/Button01"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:text="Cancel" />
  <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@id/Button01"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following property to LinearLayout-Test and Button-Button01..

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```